# delete button not showing for a permission set while logging with system admin profile

Tags: permission-sets, owd

delete button not showing on top near clone and edit properties button for a permission set while logging with system admin profile.What could be the reason for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if there are any users assigned to the permission set. If yes, you wont be able to see "Delete" near clone and edit properties button of the permission set.